Remote development in VS code using dev container "without" SSH
I am trying to connect to a Dev container installed on an EC2 instance from my VS code application. This works when I am not on the Corporate network/VPN using Remote SSH extension in VS Code. However, because Corporate networks have the Port 22 used by SSH protocol disabled I am looking for a way to do the above "without" making a direct SSH connection to the EC2 instance and disconnecting from the Corporate network.
All the articles on the internet talk about doing this with remote SSH. I am specifically looking for some suggestions to achieve this without SSH or Port 22.

You can use the ssm proxy to ssh into the port. The below guide is for Cloud9 but would work for any ec2
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/field-notes-use-aws-cloud9-to-power-your-visual-studio-code-ide/
